# Can Visual Studio Code on a Mac connect to a TFS2015 server?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, tfs-2015

I have a folder structure that is full of markdown files and images that I would like to maintain in TFS2015 (possibly using a GIT repo).

I would like this folder structure to be accessible both from some Mac computers running Visual Studio Code, and from some Windows development machines (ideally from existing installations of Visual Studio 2013, if possible, else with new installations of VSCode for Windows)

When anyone checks in anything, I want to deploy the latest and greatest content (both markdown files and images) to a web folder.

Can all the above be done?

As a note, I have all this implemented today as a VS2013 web project which connects to TFS2015 and uses a custom build to deploy on the web server. This is working, but unfortunately it cannot be accessed from OS X machines using VSCode, hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the above can be achieved. VS Code on OS X or any tool on any OS is agnostic to the host system for the  remote Git repo.

The git client being used by VS Code only cares about is the path (URL in case of TFS 2015) and the authentication/authorization mechanism to the remote git repo.

Comment: So on the Mac machines I would need a local git repo which then pushes to the remote repo using the URL of the GIT repo hosted by TFS?

Comment: That is correct. You simply need to either clone the remote repo hosted by TFS or if it is a new repo, initialize it locally and push it to TFS (thus setting it up as the "origin" remote repo)

Comment: I have done everything you described from VS Code on a windows machine connected to the TFS2015 server (pretty awesome the new build system that it provides, instead of the old XAML based, I have to admit).
As soon as SourceForge comes back online - not working now - I will try the same on a Mac using VS Code as well.